# Center div consisting of series of button using CSS

Tags: css, button, html, center

this may sound simple, I have made a div block which consists of buttons which should be lying horizontally one after another. The buttons are used for navigation and the number of buttons changes dynamically depending on the web pages.

Now my problem is to align these buttons center at the bottom of every page above the footer note and the alignment should also be in the flow depending upon the increase or decrease of the buttons.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="navButtons">
        <a href="back.php"><input type="button" value="BACK" class="butttons" /></a>              
        <a href="home.php"><input type="button" value="HOME" class="butttons" /></a>
        <a href="next.php"><input type="button" value="NEXT" class="butttons" /></a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using margin: 0 auto;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

But no success, they just stick to the left side of the page.

Here is the CSS for:

```
.container{    
    background: url('images/gray_bg.jpg');
    width: 900px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;        
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;      
}

.navButtons{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;         
}
```

Any good ideas of how this can be solved

Thanks

Comment: Have you set a width to the div?

Comment: Can you post the CSS for .container and .navButtons? It's hard to fix it if we can't see what's broken

Comment: Hi I have just updated with CSS for .container and .navButtons

Comment: See my updated answer with fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as < anchor > tags are inline items you can just do:

```
div.navButtons {
    text-align: center;
}
```

see this fiddle to see what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/ZvrZW/

Comment: Hi, your fiddle produces what I want, but my problem is that I want the buttons to remain at same position for all my pages

Comment: Maybe My answer works ? , mine does it by using HTML instead of c4urself way which is pretty awesome way of doing it !

Answer (score 1):

Okay using a bit of HTML with CSS what you want can be pretty easily done here is the link to the jsfiddle

css

```
div.container {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 100 % ;
}
div.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0em;
    width: 100 % ;
    bottom: 2em;
    overflow - y: auto;
}
div.navButtons {
    width: 100 % ;
}.navButtons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: auto;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 

    </div>
    <div class="navButtons">
        <center>
        <a href="back.php"><input type="button" value="BACK" class="butttons" /></a>              
        <a href="home.php"><input type="button" value="HOME" class="butttons" /></a>
        <a href="next.php"><input type="button" value="NEXT" class="butttons" /></a>     
               </center>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

[image: jsFiddle]